# Dynamic localization of messages

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have made a simple localization of messages. All messages are stored in the static class `Lng`

```
public static partial class Lng
{
    public static readonly string AppName = "My application";
    public static class Category1
    {
        public static readonly string ConfirmDelete = "Are you sure want to delete?";
    }
}
```

In code usage is as simple as referencing fields

```
MessageBox.Show(Lng.Category1.ConfirmDelete, ...
```

Then there is a manager, which does following:

- language selection
- load corresponding translation
- updating fields via reflection
- export currently selected language on application exit for an update (in case if default language is selected - to create first translation for any other language)

It's irrelevant of how language files looks likes, but here is a reflection part

```
TranslateLng("Lng.", typeof(Lng));
...

private static void TranslateLng(string parent, Type type)
{
    foreach (Type nested in type.GetNestedTypes())
    {
        string child = string.Format("{0}{1}.", parent, nested.Name);
        TranslateLng(child, nested);
        foreach (var field in nested.GetFields())
        {
            string key = child + field.Name;
            DefaultAdd(key, (string)field.GetValue(null)); // store value in default language dictionary (if not created yet)
            field.SetValue(null, GetValue(key)); // get value for currently selected language
        }
    }
```

---

This system has one problem: all messages are defined in one class, which required manual management (deleting and updating messages when updating code which uses them).

And I was thinking to change manager to register strings dynamically and simplify usage to something like

```
MessageBox.Show(Lng.Text("Are you sure want to delete?"), ...
```

So that text is defined right where it used, duplicated text can be handled by manager and so on.

There are however 2 problems:

- I will need a complete list of all messages at the end of application run to export complete list of messages (for currently selected language). What if some of `Lng.Text()` are never called at that run? Is there a way to register them **as they are used in code** (compile time?)? So that all calls will be registered somehow, even if peace of code is never used.
- How to generate `key`. I could use [`CallerMemberName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx), but right key are more useful, as they are telling exact purpose. To example, `Lng.Configuration.Appearance.CaptionText`. I could call `Lng.Text(key, message)`, but then I have to manage keys, ensure in their uniqueness, which doesn't appeals me.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Why aren't you using `Resources` as normal for localization? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746621(v=vs.110).aspx and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/299436/WPF-Localization-for-Dummies

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, see `problems` part. How to register method calls if they are not called (if that possible, if not - is there an alternative to what I need)? How to organize key generation? Or you could answer how would you organize that what I am trying to achieve (if it's totally different from my approach).

Comment: @Sonhja, because default localization in winforms and wpf is crap. Total crap. Managing application resources would be even less nice than using static fields (compare effort needed to add a string and referencing it in my case and in that what MS offers).

Answer (score 1):

I recently worked on a project with internationaliztion and we used `Resources` in con junction with the [Sisulizer](http://www.sisulizer.com/) program with great success. Having the resources solves your key problem as you manually enter the key when you extract the resources. You also get great support from `Resharper` which makes the whole process a breeze.

`Sisulizer` is then used to extract resources as well as strings hard-coded in our Win Forms and WPF classes. It can export a CSV which you can give your translators and it also supports [pseudo translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudolocalization), which makes testing such apps very easy as well.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not asking about how to localize. It's already localized and both works pretty: localization process and on-the-fly language selection. I am simply trying to optimize it. The `hard-coded strings` sounds interesting, but if you say `Resharper`, then it is a kind of compile time pre-processing. I am rather looking for a way of run-time pre-processing (if such exists).